# How can I make the first image of posts appear with the titles of the posts on the home page, not just a post title as Text Link?

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

I have a simple text blogger template I mean my template shows just the title without the image.

It shows on The home page just the titles of the posts as Urls for Those posts, but I need to show the first image of any post with its title on the Home page.

how can I make the first image of posts appear with the titles of the posts on the home page, not just a post title as Text Link?

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:post.title/></b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b:with value='data:post.featuredImage.isResizable ? resizeImage(data:post.featuredImage, 240, &quot;1:2&quot;) : data:post.thumbnail' var='image'>
    <img class='full' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:image'/>
    </b:with>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for contributing to SO. Please consider adding some explaination to your answer